Flet Container issue
I want to make a FLash Card app like using Flet,
the intended functionality is when user click on the car it should change to the mening of the word, both the word and its definitions come from a populated python dictionary;
SO far I haven't be able to do that the flash card update when user click on it.
below my code for suggenstion:
from wordCollection import words

def main(page: ft.Page):
    page.title = "Containers - clickable and not"
    page.vertical_alignment = ft.MainAxisAlignment.CENTER
    page.horizontal_alignment = ft.CrossAxisAlignment.CENTER

    def on_click(e) -> None:
        for i in range(len(words.values())):
            for k in words.values():
                row.controls.append(
                    ft.Container(
                        content=txt(value=k, border_color='transparent', border_width=0, disabled=True),
                        margin=10,
                        padding=10,
                        alignment=ft.alignment.center,
                        bgcolor=ft.colors.YELLOW_900,
                        width=150,
                        height=150,
                        border_radius=15
                    )
                )
    page.update()


    row = ft.Row(wrap=True, scroll="always", expand=True)
    txt = ft.TextField

    page.add(row)

    for i in range(len(words.keys())):
        for k in words.keys():
            row.controls.append(
                ft.Container(
                    content=txt(value=k, border_color='transparent', border_width=0, disabled=True),
                    margin=10,
                    padding=10,
                    alignment=ft.alignment.center,
                    bgcolor=ft.colors.CYAN_900,
                    width=150,
                    height=150,
                    border_radius=15,
                    ink=True,
                    on_click=on_click,
                )
            )
    page.update()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ft.app(target=main)

